# Access $ in a required file using Alloy

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am in my controller (`ControllerA`) and I have an external file that I want to handle orientation changes.

```
//-- In ControllerA
var gestures = require('gestures');
```

Inside `gestures.js` I need access to `$` so I can manipulate some elements in `ControllerA`

Inside `gestures.js` I currently get undefined for `$`

I have successfully managed to get this to work by creating an `init()` function in `gestures` and I can intantiate the require like:

`var gestures = require('gestures').init($);` but this feels like a hack.

What is the proper way of doing this in alloy?

**edit**
Just a side note. I tried doing this with `Ti.include()` as well and same thing...no access to `$`

Comment: i think the way you did it ( `init($)` ) is fine beacuse `gestures.js` will be a reusable component and it better to initialize its scope where ever you use it. Also dont use `Ti.include()` its depreciated.

Comment: I'm passing $ to the included file (that's just a controller object)

Comment: @turtle Ok, if that is the normal way of doing it then I will continue to do that. I just wasn't sure if their was an easier way or a more correct way

Comment: I haven't had a need to do this yet myself, but I like the method.  If you mark your method as the right answer, I think it would be interesting to hear more about what you have the gestures.js file doing for you.  I usually had orientation code inside my particular view/window code.  Perhaps it is navigation code?

Answer (score 0):

CommenJS modules (included in other controller using require ) must be independent off any other controllers. from it's name "gesture.js" i think you are trying to controle some orientations changes and shake gestures ... You have to define this module to use it in all other controllers and for that this feature exist.

for example suppose i have a module called animations.js :

```
var animations={};
animations.moveToLeft=function(element,newLeftValue){
     var animation=Ti.UI.createAnimation({
         left:newLeftValue,
         duration:700
         ... so on 
      });
      element.animate(animation);
};
module.exports=animations;
```

Then i can use this module from many other controller and to animate many titanium's objects
just require it in controller.js file and use moveToLeft function ...